# Machine Learning System Configuration (Hardware Configuration)

Tags: processor-architecture

I am working on **machine learning** project where I used **500K** images to train the model. I am using **lib-linear SVM(Support Vector Machine)** With **HOG (Feature Descriptor)**. HOG take 128X 128 images as input and produces 1096 features. Produced features vector (1096 X 500K) used as input to SVM Model Training.
My Current System Configuration is:

- Processor : Intel® Core™ i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8
- RAM: 16 GB
- Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)

which took around **5 hours and 30 minutes** to train the model.

I also tested the same task on AWS cloud and the results are:

```
Instance Type       CORE        RAM        Training Time In (Hours)            
c4.8xlarge          36          60         03:39:15
c5.4xlarge          16          32         01:23:22
```

Now, I want to build my own system and I am really confused to select processor.

Should I go for Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2699 v4 with 22 cores OR INTEL® CORE™ i9-7980XE EXTREME EDITION PROCESSOR with 18 cores?

Comment: Why limit yourself to those two options? And why use CPU instead of GPU?

Comment: I do not have much exposure to GPU Computation and GPU Devices. If possible can you suggest me the best GPU for Machine Learning?.